# How to execute MySQL query and bash command together in one script?

Tags: mysql, bash, github

I want to execute multiple SQL queries in a bash script. The queries are loading files with similar names. For example: File1.csv, File2.csv ... I know that I can use

`mysql -u root -p <<EOF
MYSQL QUERY 1
MYSQL QUERY 2
...`
 
Can I use bash variables in those queries?
I have also tried code like

```
for f in $dir; do 
echo "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE $table CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
done`
```

However, the last time I execute a script like this, my table is crashed. The sample script I used to write the above script is

```
  for f in $dumpDir/*.csv ; do
  table=`basename $f|cut -f1 -d'.'`
  echo "`date` Restoring table $table"
  echo "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE $table CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';" |$mysql || exit 1
done
```

Is my table crashed becasue I'm missing the part `|$mysql || exit 1`?

Comment: Did you mean to tag SQL Server since the question appears to be about MySQL?

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm ssh to a MySQL server remotely.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove the SQL Server tag then...

Comment: Will do. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by appending `|$mysql ||exit 1` after the MYSQL query. I also used the configuration from the ghtorrent project. [original code](https://github.com/gousiosg/github-mirror/blob/master/sql/ght-restore-mysql)